# Averages Program doesn't work (Python 3.4)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an averages program that takes numbers until the user asks the program to calculate it. I'm using a class to get better at classes and I'd like someone to explain why the code I wrote does't work when you run it and try and calculate an average.

```
from statistics import mean

class User():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.numbers = []
        self.check_name()

    def check_name(self):
        self.ask_user()
        #adding in later

    def ask_user(self):
        asking = True
        while asking:
            try:
                self.number = int(input())
                self.numbers.append(self.number)
            except ValueError:
                if str(self.number) == "calc":
                    self.calc()
                    asking = False
                    break
                else:
                    print("Only enter numbers. ")


    def calc(self):
        avg = mean(self.numbers)
        print("Average =",str(avg))

User()
```

Comment: By the way, there is no need to store `number` as a field of `User` (i.e. as `self.number`) since you're not using it anywhere else. Just use a plain local variable.

Comment: There's also no need to both `break` and set `asking = False`. Either will end the loop. Personally I prefer `break`, then you don't need an extra variable and you can write `while True`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are always attempting to convert the input string to an integer. If this fails, as it will if someone types "calc", the variable `self.number` will not be redefined.

This code works correctly if you move the call to `int()` to the next line, and remove the call to `str()`, which becomes unnecessary:

```
def ask_user(self):
    asking = True
    while asking:
        try:
            self.number = input()
            self.numbers.append(int(self.number))
        except ValueError:
            if self.number == "calc":
                self.calc()
                asking = False
                break
            else:
                print("Only enter numbers. ")
```

Comment: Thanks! Also do I need the "break" or is it unnecessary?

Comment: @GeorgeBaker: I think Alex answered this well in his second comment on your question.

Comment: @GeorgeBaker: You could create a dictionary called `self.info`. When a person enters their name, `if not self.info.has_key(name): self.info[name] = []` I see you deleted your question, but I can give more details if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you enter a number, `self.number` contains a number. When `self.number = int(input())` and `input()` returns `"calc"`, the statement fails and so `self.number` is still a number. After all, it can't be `int("calc")`.